# Can't update dictionary's column in postgres DB because of double quotes?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psql

I can update the column in question in two CLI commands:

```
psql -U postgres
UPDATE taskt SET update= '[{"id": 0, "timestamp": "2019-12-17T22:16:28.985Z", "statusUpdate": "three little piggies"}]' WHERE uri = '/rest/tasks/xyz';
```

That works just fine, but I am going to running the commands in python and doing something like subprocess.check_output(cli_0 + " & " + cli_1, shell=True) results in thinking the second is a bash command.  I would ideally like to run something like:

```
psql -U postgres -c "UPDATE taskt SET update= '[{"id": 0, "timestamp": "2019-12-17T22:16:28.985Z", "statusUpdate": "three little piggies"}]' WHERE uri = '/rest/tasks/xyz';"
```

But the double quotes in the dictionary kinda kills that idea.  Turning them into single quotes also doesn't work.  Any suggestions would be incredibly helpful.  I have access to python3.5 and I can't pip install anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to backslash escape the inner double-quotes:

```
psql -U postgres -c "UPDATE taskt SET update= '[{\"id\": 0, \"timestamp\": \"2019-12-17T22:16:28.985Z\", \"statusUpdate\": \"three little piggies\"}]' WHERE uri = '/rest/tasks/xyz';"
```

Otherwise, you can save to file and run it:

```
cat <<_EOF_ > /tmp/myfile
> UPDATE taskt SET update= '[{"id": 0, "timestamp": "2019-12-17T22:16:28.985Z", "statusUpdate": "three little piggies"}]' WHERE uri = '/rest/tasks/xyz';
> _EOF_
psql -U postgres < /tmp/myfile
```

You should also be able to do a heredoc directly into `psql`:

```
psql postgres postgres <<_EOF_
> select 1;
> _EOF_
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
psql U postgres <<_EOF_
UPDATE taskt SET update= '[{"id": 0, "timestamp": "2019-12-17T22:16:28.985Z", "statusUpdate": "three little piggies"}]' WHERE uri = '/rest/tasks/xyz';
_EOF_
```

Comment: Backslashing the inner double-quotes worked on the CLi but when I run it in python, the backslashes go away unforunately.  I'll try saving it off to a doc, but its not my favorite idea.